# Android 7.1 for x86_64 booting to cmd line but not displaying the GUI on AMD PC

Tags: amd-processor, android-x86

I have build the Android 7.1 for x86_64 and installed on an AMD64 machine. I need to install some custom apk on the Anroid PC (AMD). Tried using the Android PC as device for ADB but it is not getting listed for "adb devices". Seems required to set the USB debugging option. But the problem is the Android is booting fine but remains in the command line only and not displaying the graphics. Is it because of the graphics card driver from AMD? Can you please provide some inputs? Just to mention, if installed on Intel machine the same image is moving ahead and displaying the graphics.